# errors with updating halide function in all pixel

Tags: halide

I try to implement an optical flow algorithm in Halide. I have some problems with the update of u and v vectors. Here is my C++ version:

```
for(int i= 0; i<h; i++) {
for(int j= 0; j<bpl; j++) {
  float iix = Ix[i*bpl+j];
  float iiy = Iy[i*bpl+j];
  float iit = It[i*bpl+j];
  for(int k=0; k<40; k++) {
    float Uav     = (u[(i-1)*bpl+j] + u[(i+1)*bpl+j] + u[i*bpl+j-1] + u[i*bpl+j+1])/4;
    float Vav     = (v[(i-1)*bpl+j] + v[(i+1)*bpl+j] + v[i*bpl+j-1] + v[i*bpl+j+1])/4;
    float P       = iix*Uav + iiy*Vav + iit;
    float D       = iix*iix + iiy*iiy + lambda*lambda;
    float tmp     = P/D;
    float utmp    = Uav - iix*tmp;
    float vtmp    = Vav - iiy*tmp;
    u[i*bpl+j] = utmp;
    v[i*bpl+j] = vtmp;
  }
}
```

}

And this is my halide implementation:

```
Func u("u"), v("v");
Func Uav("Uav"), Vav("Vav"), P("P"), D("D"), tmp("tmp"), utmp("utmp"), vtmp("vtmp");
RDom r_0(0, input_1.width(), 0, input_1.height());
u(x, y, c) = 0;
v(x, y, c) = 0;
for(int k=0; k<40; k++) {
Uav (x, y, c) = (u(x, y-1, c) + u(x, y+1, c) + u(x-1, y, c) + u(x+1, y, c))/4;
Vav (x, y, c) = (v(x, y-1, c) + v(x, y+1, c) + v(x-1, y, c) + v(x+1, y, c))/4;
P (x, y, c) = Ix(x, y, c) * Uav(x, y, c) + Iy(x, y, c) * Vav(x, y, c) + It(x, y, c);
D (x, y, c) = Ix(x, y, c) * Ix(x, y, c) + Iy(x, y, c) * Iy(x, y, c) + lambda * lambda;
tmp (x, y, c) = P(x, y, c)/D(x, y, c);
utmp(x, y, c) = Uav(x, y, c) - Ix(x, y, c) * tmp(x, y, c);
vtmp(x, y, c) = Vav(x, y, c) - Iy(x, y, c) * tmp(x, y, c);
u(r_0.x, r_0.y, c) = utmp(x, y, c);
v(r_0.x, r_0.y, c) = vtmp(x, y, c);
}
```

When I run my program, I get the following runtime error:

> Error:
>   Func u cannot be given a new update definition, because it has already been realized or used in the definition of another Func.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Thanks for yours responses.

As say, AhiyaHiya, variables x, y, c are declared as:

Var x("x"), y("y"), c("c");

As you suggested, I use an extern c++ function to update my Halide functions. Here is my extern function:

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT buffer_t compute_flow(buffer_t *Ix, buffer_t *Iy, buffer_t *It, buffer_t *u, buffer_t *v, 
                                       const int32_t bpl, const int32_t h, const float lambda, const uint8_t IsU) {
    //about Ix
    const auto min0_ix = Ix->min[0];
    const auto internalX_ix = min0_ix;
    const auto min1_ix = Ix->min[1];
    const auto internalY_ix = min1_ix;
    const auto stride0_ix = Ix->stride[0];
    const auto stride1_ix = Ix->stride[1];
    const auto x_ix = bpl + internalX_ix;
    const auto y_ix = h + internalY_ix;
        //about Iy
    const auto min0_iy = Iy->min[0];
    const auto internalX_iy = min0_iy;
    const auto min1_iy = Iy->min[1];
    const auto internalY_iy = min1_iy;
    const auto stride0_iy = Iy->stride[0];
    const auto stride1_iy = Iy->stride[1];
    const auto x_iy = bpl + internalX_iy;
    const auto y_iy = h + internalY_iy;

    //about It
    const auto min0_it = It->min[0];
    const auto internalX_it = min0_it;
    const auto min1_it = It->min[1];
    const auto internalY_it = min1_it;
    const auto stride0_it = It->stride[0];
    const auto stride1_it = It->stride[1];
    const auto x_it = bpl + internalX_it;
    const auto y_it = h + internalY_it;

    const auto iix = *(Ix->host + (x_ix - min0_ix) * stride0_ix + (y_ix - min1_ix) * stride1_ix);
    const auto iiy = *(Iy->host + (x_iy - min0_iy) * stride0_iy + (y_iy - min1_iy) * stride1_iy);
    const auto iit = *(It->host + (x_it - min0_it) * stride0_it + (y_it - min1_it) * stride1_it);

    //about u
    const auto min0_u = u->min[0];
    const auto internalX_u = min0_u;
    const auto min1_u = u->min[1];
    const auto internalY_u = min1_u;
    const auto stride0_u = u->stride[0];
    const auto stride1_u = u->stride[1];
    const auto x_u = bpl + internalX_u;
    const auto y_u = h + internalY_u;
      //about v
    const auto min0_v = v->min[0];
    const auto internalX_v = min0_v;
    const auto min1_v = v->min[1];
    const auto internalY_v = min1_v;
    const auto stride0_v = v->stride[0];
    const auto stride1_v = v->stride[1];
    const auto x_v = bpl + internalX_v;
    const auto y_v = h + internalY_v;

    buffer_t *uResult, *vResult;

    for(int k=0; k<40; k++) {
      const auto u0 = *(u->host + (x_u - min0_u) * stride0_u + (y_u - 1 - min1_u) * stride1_u); //u[(i-1)*bpl+j] 
      const auto u1 = *(u->host + (x_u - min0_u) * stride0_u + (y_u + 1 - min1_u) * stride1_u); //u[(i+1)*bpl+j]
      const auto u2 = *(u->host + (x_u - 1 - min0_u) * stride0_u + (y_u - min1_u) * stride1_u); //u[i*bpl+j-1]
      const auto u3 = *(u->host + (x_u + 1 - min0_u) * stride0_u + (y_u - min1_u) * stride1_u); //u[i*bpl+j+1]

      const auto v0 = *(v->host + (x_v - min0_v) * stride0_v + (y_v - 1 - min1_v) * stride1_v); //v[(i-1)*bpl+j] 
      const auto v1 = *(v->host + (x_v - min0_v) * stride0_v + (y_v + 1 - min1_v) * stride1_v); //v[(i+1)*bpl+j]
      const auto v2 = *(v->host + (x_v - 1 - min0_v) * stride0_v + (y_v - min1_v) * stride1_v); //v[i*bpl+j-1]
      const auto v3 = *(v->host + (x_v + 1 - min0_v) * stride0_v + (y_v - min1_v) * stride1_v); //v[i*bpl+j+1]

      const auto Uav     = (u0 + u1 + u2 + u3)/4;
      const auto Vav     = (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3)/4;
      const auto P       = iix*Uav + iiy*Vav + iit;
      const auto D       = iix*iix + iiy*iiy + lambda*lambda;
      const auto tmp     = P/D;
      const auto utmp    = Uav - iix*tmp;
      const auto vtmp    = Vav - iiy*tmp;

      *(u->host + (x_u - min0_u) * stride0_u + (y_u - min1_u) * stride1_u) = utmp; //u[i*bpl+j]
      *(v->host + (x_v - min0_v) * stride0_v + (y_v - min1_v) * stride1_v) = vtmp; //v[i*bpl+j]

      if(IsU)
        *(uResult->host + (x_u - min0_u) * stride0_u + (y_u - min1_u) * stride1_u) = utmp;
      else
        *(vResult->host + (x_v - min0_v) * stride0_v + (y_v - min1_v) * stride1_v) = vtmp;
    }

    if(IsU) return *uResult;
    else return *vResult;
```

}

And in my main, I call it as follows:

```
    const float lambda = 0.05;

    Image<uint8_t> input_1 = load_image(argv[1]);
    Image<uint8_t> input_2 = load_image(argv[1]);

    Var x("x"); //image indice in x direction
    Var y("y"); //image indice in y direction
    Var c("c"); //image number of channel

    //clamp to edge
    Func clamped_1("clamped_1"), clamped_2("clamped_2");
    clamped_1 = BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge(input_1);
    clamped_2 = BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge(input_2);

    //convert rgb image to grayscale image
    Func f_1("f_1"), f_2("f_2");
    f_1(x,y,c) = min(0.299f * clamped_1(x,y,0) + 0.587f * clamped_1(x,y,1) + 0.114f * clamped_1(x,y,2), 255.0f);
    f_2(x,y,c) = min(0.299f * clamped_2(x,y,0) + 0.587f * clamped_2(x,y,1) + 0.114f * clamped_2(x,y,2), 255.0f);

    //gaussian bluring
    Image<float> kernel(5, 5);
    kernel(0, 1) = 0.000067; kernel(0, 1) = 0.001663; kernel(0, 2) = 0.004706; kernel(0, 3) = 0.001663; kernel(0, 4) = 0.000067;
    kernel(1, 0) = 0.001663; kernel(1, 1) = 0.041482; kernel(1, 2) = 0.117381; kernel(1, 3) = 0.041482; kernel(1, 4) = 0.001663;
    kernel(2, 0) = 0.004706; kernel(2, 1) = 0.117381; kernel(2, 2) = 0.332152; kernel(2, 3) = 0.117381; kernel(2, 4) = 0.004706;
    kernel(3, 0) = 0.001663; kernel(3, 1) = 0.041482; kernel(3, 2) = 0.117381; kernel(3, 3) = 0.041482; kernel(3, 4) = 0.001663;
    kernel(4, 0) = 0.000067; kernel(4, 1) = 0.001663; kernel(4, 2) = 0.004706; kernel(4, 3) = 0.001663; kernel(4, 4) = 0.000067;
    RDom r(kernel);
    Func I1("I1"), I2("I2");
    I1(x, y, c) = sum(f_1(x+r.x, y+r.y, c) * kernel(r.x, r.y));
    I2(x, y, c) = sum(f_2(x+r.x, y+r.y, c) * kernel(r.x, r.y));

    //inputs derivations
    Func Ix("Ix"), Iy("Iy"), It("It");
    Ix(x, y, c) = (-I1(x-1, y-1, c) + I1(x, y-1, c) - I1(x-1, y, c) + I1(x, y, c)) + 
                  (-I2(x-1, y-1, c) + I2(x, y-1, c) - I2(x-1, y, c) + I2(x, y, c));
    Iy(x, y, c) = (-I1(x-1, y-1, c) - I1(x, y-1, c) + I1(x-1, y, c) + I1(x, y, c)) + 
                  (-I2(x-1, y-1, c) - I2(x, y-1, c) + I2(x-1, y, c) + I2(x, y, c));
    It(x, y, c) = (-I1(x-1, y-1, c) - I1(x, y-1, c) - I1(x-1, y, c) - I1(x, y, c)) - 
                  ( I2(x-1, y-1, c) + I2(x, y-1, c) + I2(x-1, y, c) + I2(x, y, c));

    Func u("u"), v("v");
    u(x, y, c) = 0; v(x, y, c) = 0;

    Func callU("callU"), callV("callV");
    vector<ExternFuncArgument> argsU(9);
    argsU[0] = Ix;                   argsU[1] = Iy;            argsU[2] = It;
    argsU[3] = u;                    argsU[4] = v;             argsU[5] = input_1.width();
    argsU[6] = input_1.height();     argsU[7] = lambda;        argsU[8] = 1;
    vector<ExternFuncArgument> argsV(9);
    argsV[0] = Ix;                   argsV[1] = Iy;            argsV[2] = It;
    argsV[3] = u;                    argsV[4] = v;             argsV[5] = input_1.width();
    argsV[6] = input_1.height();     argsV[7] = lambda;        argsV[8] = 0;
    vector<Type> types(9);
    types[0] = Ix.output_types()[0]; types[1] = Iy.output_types()[0]; types[2] = It.output_types()[0];
    types[3] = u.output_types()[0];  types[4] = v.output_types()[0];  types[5] = Int(32);
    types[6] = Int(32);              types[7] = Float(32);            types[8] = UInt(8);

    callU.define_extern("compute_flow", argsU, types, 1);
    callV.define_extern("compute_flow", argsV, types, 1);

    Func outputU("outputU"), outputV("outputV");
    outputU(x, y, c) = callU(x, y, c);
    outputV(x, y, c) = callV(x, y, c);

    Ix.compute_root();
    Iy.compute_root();
    It.compute_root();
    outputU.compile_jit();
    outputV.compile_jit();

    Image<uint8_t> out_u = outputU.realize(input_1.width(), input_1.height(), input_1.channels());
    Image<uint8_t> out_v = outputV.realize(input_1.width(), input_1.height(), input_1.channels());
```

When I don't schedule u and v, all compile well, but I get this runtime error:

> Error: Func u cannot be scheduled to be computed inline, because it is used in the externally-computed function callU Aborted (core dumped)

But when I schedule both u and v as:

```
    u.compute_root();
    v.compute_root();
```

I get the following runtime error:

> Internal error at /home/rokiatou/Documents/Thèse/halide/Halide-master/src/BoundsInference.cpp:283 Condition failed: b.empty() || b.size() == func_args.size() Aborted (core dumped)

I'm not sure if my external function compute_flow is well defined. I can not solve the scheduling problem.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you writing the same values to `u[i*bpl+j]` and `v[i*bpl+j]` 40 times with no other side effects? Are `u[]` and `v[]` supposed to be initialized to something or maybe they come from some other source?

Comment: The error message is pointing out that you update the definition of `u` after you use it to generate `Uav`.

Comment: Possibly you want to generate `u_out[]` and `v_out[]` vs. updating `u[]` and `v[]` in place. Maybe you want to run this process over some data 40 times. If so, it might be easier to implement one generation in Halide and call it 40 times.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the variables x,y,c are declared as Halide::Var; if that were the case, then the above listed error is actually accurate.

You can use a c++ for-loop to add update definitions to your Halide::Func, but you would need to use regular C or C++ style variables to do so, at least in one variable spot; the code you have above just references the same variables over and over.

Regarding access to the pixels you listed, "(x-1, y, c), (x+1, y, c), (x, y, c), (x, y-1, c)[...]" here is an example of accessing a value within a buffer_t* in an extern Halide func:

```
extern "C" void 
auto get_something_done_in_c(buffer_t* my_buffer, const int32_t dx, const int32_t dy)
{
    const auto min0       = my_buffer->min[0];
    const auto internal_x = min0;

    const auto min1       = my_buffer->min[1];
    const auto internal_y = min1;

    const auto stride0 = my_buffer->stride[0];
    const auto stride1 = my_buffer->stride[1];

    const auto x1 = dx + internal_x;
    const auto y1 = dy + internal_y;

    const auto value =  *(my_buffer->host + (x1 - min0) * stride0 + (y1 - min1) * stride1);

    return value;
}
HalideExtern_3(int32_t, get_something_done_in_c, buffer_t, int32_t, int32_t);
```

To explain a little about how to get the 'value'... I use the my_buffer variable to get access to the data pointer, known as host. That host variable returns the pointer address for the data that you care about. Since this is a 1 dimensional buffer, you use the x and y coordinates, multiplied by stride0 and stride1 to get the address offset within the data pointer to get the value you care about.